# Cant install OAuth module

Tags: php, oauth

Already sitting on this issue for 2 day's checked many postes related to it here and all around the internet and still can't find what is the f problem..

I need to install this OAuth module (Pecl PHP Extention) I have my site on bitnami server so i tried allready 3 time with different guides (https://wiki.bitnami.com/Components/PHP#How_to_install_OAuth_module.3f)
(http://www.mkfoster.com/2009/01/04/how-to-install-a-php-pecl-extensionmodule-on-ubuntu/)
(and included all needed in php.ini) and still when i cheching with "php -m" in ssh and with  phpinfo(); test page in not seems to be installed ,,, forgot to say i need it for  implementing  shapeways api  when i am trying the implement the OAuth authentication it's crashing... if somebody have new ideas or maybe something i missed  i would be glad to hear..

Comment: As an aside - frequently php on the command line can have a different php.ini than the Apache version. Check for different folders in /etc/php5 for the cli and apache directories. Have you restarted apache? The changes won't be applied until restarted.

Comment: know this issue about php.ini  checked and updated  both directories    /etc/php5/cli  ,    /opt/bitnami/php/etc         restarted the server with "sudo /opt/bitnami/ctlscript.sh restart apache" command...

Comment: I know that it successfully installed for sure but it not loaded...

Answer (score 0):

Bitnami developer here

Please try to run `which php` and check that the result is `/opt/bitnami/php/bin/php`.

Check you have a `oauth.so` in `/opt/bitnami/php/lib/php/extensions/`

In the last step of our wiki, you can add `extension = '/opt/bitnami/php/lib/php/extensions/oauth.so'` at the end of /opt/bitnami/php/etc/php.ini, or uncomment `;extension=oauth.so` in the same file.

I hope it helps

David